# Best way to render an existing canvas instance

Tags: android, canvas

I get a Canvas instance from an external library (that does some off-screen rendering in there)

I want to display the content of this canvas now in my application.

I normally have 2 possibilities to draw a canvas (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html):

1. Implement View and override onDraw()
2. Implement SurfaceView, and draw on my own

But both solutions have a predefined canvas (onDraw passes in the View canvas, and SurfaceView can only render on the Canvas I can retrieve via SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas())

Is there any chance that I can take my "external" canvas and render it on View or SurfaceView (or easily merge it with their canvas) ?

Comment: what is external canvas?

Comment: View and Surface view come with their canvas. I get my Canvas instance from an external library, and that Canvas should be rendered now.

Comment: so what do you want to do with that canvas?

Comment: I want to render that canvas I get from my external library in my View/ViewSurface. I saw no easy way to do that, since View and SurfaceView only renders their own Canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I missed the most obvious one:

```
SurfaceView.draw(Canvas canvas)
```